# how to publish to add a user to a role using php sdk in facebook graph api

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I want to make a user as administrator of my app using php-sdk for graph api.
This is the code provided by facebook in docs-

```
/* PHP SDK v4.0.0 */
/* make the API call */
$request = new FacebookRequest(
$session,
'POST',
'/{app-id}/roles',
array (
'user' => '123456789',
'role' => 'administrators',
)
);
$response = $request->execute();
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
/* handle the result */
```

*Edit:*
I went through this code, but it says in docs, "A user access token for any admin of the app is required.".
I'am not getting further, how to accomplish this.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    require_once('Facebook/FacebookSession.php');
    require_once('Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php');
    require_once('Facebook/FacebookRequest.php');
    require_once('Facebook/FacebookResponse.php');
    require_once('Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php');
    require_once('Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php');
    require_once('Facebook/FacebookAuthorizationException.php');
    require_once('Facebook/GraphObject.php');
    require_once('Facebook/GraphUser.php');
    require_once('Facebook/GraphSessionInfo.php');
    require_once( 'Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookHttpable.php' );
    require_once( 'Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurl.php' );
    require_once( 'Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurlHttpClient.php' );
    require_once( 'Facebook/Entities/AccessToken.php' );
    require_once( 'Facebook/Entities/SignedRequest.php' );

    use Facebook\FacebookSession;
    use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
    use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
    use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
    use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
    use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
    use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
    use Facebook\GraphObject;
    use Facebook\GraphUser;
    use Facebook\GraphSessionInfo;

    // init app with app id (APPID) and secret (SECRET)
    FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('my-app-id','my-app-secret');
    $helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper( 'Redirect URL' );

    try 
    {
      $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
    } 
    catch( Exception $ex ) 
    {
      // When validation fails or other local issues
    }

    // see if we have a session
    if(isset($session))
    {
        $_SESSION['token'] = $session->getToken();
    $token='Hard Coded access_token of admin of app';

        echo "Logged in successfully.";
        $user_id = $session->getSessionInfo()->asArray()['user_id'];
        $request = new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/App-ID/roles?access_token='.$token,array('user' => $user_id,'role' => 'administrators'));
        $response = $request->execute();
        $graph = $response->getGraphObject(GraphUser::className());
        echo "<br>Hi ". $graph->getId()."<br>";
    } 
    else 
    {
      // show login url
      $params = array(
      'scope' => 'user_friends,email,user_photos,offline_access');

      echo '<a href="' . $helper->getLoginUrl($params) . '">Login</a>';
    }
    ?>
```

access_token provided, but now it gives error as "Invalid appsecret_proof provided in the API argument".
I also enabled appsecret_proof tht in app, n passed this in app as-

```
    $appsecret_proof= hash_hmac('sha256', $token,'App-Secret'); 
    $request = new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/App-ID/roles?access_token='.$token.'&appsecret_proof='.$appsecret_proof,array('user' => $user_id,'role' => 'administrators'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a user access token to the request.  When you authenticate a user, you should be able to retrieve an access token for the user.  You haven't provided a login flow, so I can't see if you can retrieve this.

Anyways, once you've acquired a user access token just append it to the request like so:

```
$request=new FacebookRequest($session,'POST','/{app-id}/roles?access_token={access_token}',array('user'=>'123456789','role'=>'administrators')); 

$response=$request->execute(); 

$graphObject=$response->getGraphObject();
```

The docs show a phantom `,` within the request after `'role'->'administrators'`.  Its not required I don't believe (and may cause an error, although your request seemed to generate a response).

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/app/roles